# How to add the Placeholder Window in Xcode

Tags: objective-c, ios5

Going though a tutorial on youtube with Xcode and IOS programming. How do you show the PlaceHolder Window showing the file owner. The tutorial is showing how to add a couple of delegates and data source

For a visual see http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IqDZHgI_s24 at 2:55

Answer (score 16):

You may simply need to click the Hide/Show Document Outline button in the XIB editor:

[image]

Note that the File's Owner and First Responder placeholders are accessible (as the large cube icons) even when the document outline is hidden.

Another possibility is that you have created the project using a storyboard.  A storyboard doesn't have the File's Owner placeholder.  If that happened, since you are working throw a beginner tutorial, you should just start over with a new project and make sure you uncheck the “Use storyboards” checkbox in the new project wizard.

Comment: I used [ScreenFlow](http://www.telestream.net/screenflow/) to record the screen and edit the video down to size.  Then I used Photoshop to convert the movie to an animated GIF.