# How do I show the placeholder window in Xcode?

Tags: ios

I am an iOS noob and I've gotten stuck while trying to do a tutorial from O'Reilly's headfirst iphone development 2e. The tutorial wants me to drag the picker to the placeholder menu as shown in the picture below--but I can't seem to make this menu visible in xcode.

What do I do to show the placeholder menu?

[image]

If I need to click the "Disclosure button" as suggested in an answer to this question, where do I find it in the interface? In the navigators? The utilities?

[image]

Here is my screen in xcode:

[image]

This guy seems to be having a similar problem [How to add the Placeholder Window in Xcode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9766791/how-to-add-the-placeholder-window-in-xcode) (unanswered)

Comment: Edit your post to include a screenshot of your Xcode window so we can see what you see.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to add the Placeholder Window in Xcode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9766791/how-to-add-the-placeholder-window-in-xcode)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that you have created your project with a storyboard.  Storyboards do not have a File's Owner placeholder.  Since you're a self-described noob, you should just start a new project and make sure you turn **off** the “Use Storyboard” checkbox when you are going through the new project wizard.

Answer (score 0):

Right click or control click over the picker and that window should pop up. Then drag (not control drag) from the open circle up to file's owner.

Comment: thanks! I don't see placeholders or file's owner and don't know how to make xcode show them. My question is: how can i make xcode show placeholders/file's owners.

Comment: There's a little disclosure button down on the left side of the main canvas that you can click to expand that left side